# Convert ASP Reverse/Forward DNS checker to C#

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ip-address, hostname

Hi I am having to rewrite lots of VBScript/ASP code to .NET C# and one of the pieces is a script to check a user by their IP doing a forward/reverse DNS check.

The reason was that one clever hacker years ago managed to get a page indexed with a link containing an sql injection hack vector in the link and my custom defence system ended up banning GoogleBot as it saw it as the attacker.

I do have a list of as many legit SERP IP ranges as possible but in case new ones come online I need a way to prevent me banning GoogleBot instead of a hacker with a GoogleBOT user-agent.

I was using a COM component that allowed me to specify the DNS server to use and as well as my companies DNS server I had 2 backup IP ranges 6.6.6.6 & 8.8.8.8 to use if I needed to.

What I am having trouble with is setting the DNS Server IP to use for making DNS requests with my C# code.

Does anyone know how I can override the default address it must be using when I do commands like

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("202.1.3.12");
hostname = hostInfo.HostName.ToString();
```

Without setting registry keys as someone previously suggested on another forum?

I thought there maybe an easy setting to specify the IP of the DNS server to use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So what happens if you just stop doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do this with the basic apis.

The codeplex project [DnDns](https://dndns.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20do%20a%20basic%20name%20lookup&referringTitle=Documentation) looks like it will do what you want though.

Comment: so Ill need a component to set/re-set the DNS server IPS ?? or just to do a basic forward/reverse DNS check?

Comment: as I could manage without the redundancy and blame the techie boys if our DNS server goes down :)

Comment: You don't change the IPs of the DNS servers for the whole system, you just make a request from your application to the DNS server you want. After all, DNS is just an application layer protocol.